# positioning a div relative to body and not parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am loading a dynamically created webpage from a MySQL db.

I set the page up as normal but when I get to the content part of the page, I run a while loop and load the page elements according to what is stored in the database.

This works great for me except when I load a stripe which is positioned according to the body and not the content and has a width of 100% of the page and not 100% of the content.

Is there a way to position the stripe elements with jquery or javascript so they are relative to the body.

Each element in the db has positons for top and left, and have heights and width, as well as many more things like borders etc.

I load the element inside a div and set the css as inline like so

```php
   <div id="shape" style="position:absolute;top:<? echo $row['box_top']; ?>px;left:<? echo $row['box_left']; ?>px;height:<? echo $row['box_height']; ?>px;width:100%;z-index:<? echo $row['zindex']; ?>;border-top-width:<? echo $row['border_width']; ?>px;border-bottom-width:<? echo $row['border_width']; ?>px; border-style:<? echo $row['border_style']; ?>;padding:<? echo $row['padding']; ?>; opacity:<? echo $row['image_opacity']; ?>;filter:alpha(opacity=<? echo $ieopacity; ?>)"><? echo $row['content']; ?></div>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Every element is positioned relative to it's closest `relative` parent. If you need something positioned relative to the `<body>`, it' needs to be the direct child of that element. You can use javascript to 'fake' this, but a better solution would be to properly organise your HTML.

Comment: any ideas on how I can 'fake' this in JS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `position: fixed;` then.

Comment: we have a winner. thanks for this, so easy when you know how :-)

Answer (score 4):

Is sounds like your problem is that the element is nested in the middle of a load of content?

If so, you could use JavaScript to pull the element out off the DOM, and then insert it again as a direct child of the body.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#shape").prependTo($("body"));
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was searching

Answer (score 2):

use

```
body {
      position:relative;
}
```

> and make the element, which has to be absolute positioned,a direct
>   child to the body

Answer (score 0):

Use the below.

```
body{
    position:relative;
}
```

This will make all the absolute positioned elements inside the body to be relatively positioned to the body.

Comment: Not quite. If there is a child element which is also `position: relative` any children that element has would be positioned relative to that, not the body.

Comment: Agreed @RoryMcCrossan, but as I mentioned that only absolutely positioned elements shall be positioned relatively to the body, if and ofcourse they are within the body tag if body is set to position relative.